# Efficiently add builds to all slides in Keynote 6.2

Tags: keynote, iwork

I would like to have all of my slides build the bullet lists with Appear / By Bullet (animation, build in: appear, delivery: by bullet). In Keynote prior to version 6, it was possible to set a build in the master slide. Keynote 6 has removed that option. I find I'm manually going through every slide to add this animation.

Is there some way to do this in a more automated / efficient way?

Answer (score 1):

Under the "format" menu, you should be able to copy the animation you want and paste it for any other object. Does that not work?

Comment: But I still have to click on each slide right? I want to change a whole bunch of slides in one go.

Answer (score 1):

In previous version of Keynote you could add animations to a section of the master, and those would apply to all slides with that master. It appears that Apple in its wisdom has disabled this feature. So the previous answer is correct: the only way to "automate" is to paste the animation into each slide.